# Java - first http request to specific host significantly slower

Tags: java, benchmarking, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am writing a benchmarking tool to run against a web application. The problem that I am facing is that the first request to the server always takes significantly longer than subsequent requests.
I have experienced this problem with the apache http client 3.x, 4.x and the [Google http client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/). The apache http client 4.x shows the biggest difference (first request takes about seven times longer than subsequent ones. For Google and 3.x it is about 3 times longer.

My tool has to be able to benchmark simultaneous requests with threads. I can not use one instance of e.g. HttpClient and call it from all the threads, since this throws a Concurrent exception. Therefore, I have to use an individual instance in each thread, which will only execute a single request. This changes the overall results dramatically.

I do not understand this behavior. I do not think that it is due to a caching mechanism on the server because a) the webapp under consideration does not employ any caching (to my knowledge) and b) this effect is also visible when first requesting www.hostxy.com and afterwards www.hostxy.com/my/webapp.

I use System.nanoTime() immediately before and after calling `client.execute(get)` or `get.execute()`, respectively.

Does anyone have an idea where this behavior stems from? Do these httpclients themselves do any caching? I would be very grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html for connection pooling.

Your first connection probably takes the longest, because its a Connect: keep-alive connection, thus following connections can reuse that connection, once it has been established. This is justa  guess

Comment: I tried disabling keep-alive, but I am not sure if I succeeded. Nevertheless, the difference also occurs, if I wait 25 seconds between subsequent requests - the keep alive timeout should have occured in this time, shouldnt it? I also do not understand why the apache http client 4.x takes so much longer than 3.x

Comment: Hmm. If I were you I'd whip out Wireshark and check out what is going over the wire. Also, read about PoolingClientConnectionManager for HttpClient. This might give you an idea on how to avoid this issue altogether

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting a JSP for the first time after server start?  If the server flushes it's working directory on each start, then the first hit the JSPs compile and it takes a long time.

Also done on the first transaction: If the transaction uses a ca cert trust store, it will be loaded and cached.

Answer (score 0):

You better once see it about caching 
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that "first http request to specific host significantly slower", maybe the cause of this symptom is on the server, while you are concerned about the client.

If the "specific host" that you are calling is an Google App Engine application (or any other Cloud Plattform), it is normal that the first call to that application make you wait a little more. That is because Google put it under a dormant state upon inactivity.

After a recent call (that usually takes longer to respond), the subsequent calls have faster responses, because the server instances are all awake.

Take a look on this: 
[Google App Engine Application Extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854821/google-app-engine-application-extremely-slow)

I hope it helps you, good luck!