# Google App-Engine Datastore is extremely slow

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine

I need help in understanding why the below code is taking 3 to 4 seconds.

UPDATE: Use case for my application is to get the activity feed of a person since last login. This feed could contain updates from friends or some new items outside of his network that he may find interesting. The Activity table stores all such activities and when a user logs in, I run a query on the GAE-DataStore to return above activities. My application supports infinite scrolling too, hence I need the cursor feature of GAE. At a given time, I get around 32 items but the activities table could have millions of rows (as it contains data from all the users).

Currently the Activity table is small and contains 25 records only and the below java code reads only 3 records from the same table.

Each record in the Activity table has 4 UUID fields.

I cannot imagine how the query would behave if the table contained millions of rows and result contained 100s of rows.

Is there something wrong with the below code I have below?

(I am using Objectify and app-engine cursors)

```
Filter filter = new FilterPredicate("creatorID", FilterOperator.EQUAL, userId);
Query<Activity> query = ofy().load().type(Activity.class).filter(filter);
query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(previousCursorString));
QueryResultIterator<Activity> itr = query.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    Activity a = itr.next();
    System.out.println (a);
}
```

I have gone through [Google App Engine Application Extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854821/google-app-engine-application-extremely-slow) and verified that response time improves if I keep on refreshing my page (which calls the above code). However, the improvement is only ~30%

Compare this with any other database and the response time for such tiny data is in milliseconds, not even 100s of milliseconds.

Am I wrong in expecting a regular database kind of performance from the GAE DataStore?

I do not want to turn on memcache just yet as I want to improve this layer without caching first.

Comment: Are you able to provide any specific timing details from Appstats / Cloud Trace?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what your query is supposed to do but it doesn't look like it requires a cursor query. In my humble opinion the only valid use case for cursor queries is a paginated query for data with a limited count of result rows. Since your query does not have a limit i don't see why you would want to use a cursor at all.

When you need millions of results you're probably doing ad-hoc analysis of data (as no human could ever interpret millions of raw data rows) you might be better off using BigQuery instead of the appengine datastore. I'm just guessing here, but for normal front end apps you rarely need millions of rows in a result but only a few (maybe hundreds at times) which you filter from the total available rows.

Another thing:

Are you sure that it is the query that takes long? It might as well be the wrapper around the query. Since you are using cursors you would have to recall the query until there are no more results. The handling of this could be costly.

Lastly:

Are you testing on appengine itself or on the local development server? The devserver can obviouily not simulate a cloud and thus could be slower (or faster) than the real thing at times. The devserver does not know about instance warmup times either when your query spawns new instances.

Speaking of cloud: The thing about cloud databases is not that they have the best performance for very little data but that they scale and perform consistently with a couple of hundreds and a couple of billions of rows.

Edit:

> After performing a retrieval operation, the application can obtain a
>   cursor, which is an opaque base64-encoded string marking the index
>   position of the last result retrieved.
>
> [...]
>
> The cursor's position is defined as the location in the result list
>   after the last result returned. A cursor is not a relative position in
>   the list (it's not an offset); it's a marker to which the Datastore
>   can jump when starting an index scan for results. If the results for a
>   query change between uses of a cursor, the query notices only changes
>   that occur in results after the cursor. If a new result appears before
>   the cursor's position for the query, it will not be returned when the
>   results after the cursor are fetched.
>   ([Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Query_cursors))

These two statements make be believe that the query performance should be consistent with or without cursor queries.

Here are some more things you might want to check:

- How do you register your entity classes with objectify?
- What does your actual test code look like? I'd like to see how and where you measure.
- Can you share a comparison between cursor query and query without cursors?
- Improvement with multiple request could be the result of Objectifys integrated caching. You might want to disable caching for datastore performance tests

Comment: Thanks konqi. I have added use-case for using cursors in my problem description. Also, I am sure that its the query that is taking that long as I have done careful instrumentation around the datastore calls. Even the appstats shows the datastore to be the culprit. Testing for the above is done on actual GAE and not the development server.

Comment: From your usecase i'd say that you should query all the information relevant for an active user and cache the data in memcache. Then serve the data from memcache unless the cache gets evicted or updated. Funny enough the scenario you describe is similar to the sample application that students develop as preparation for their certification ;-)

Comment: ... i know that this sounds like the datastore is generally crap and slow, but it's actually not. It's just different and consistently *fast* for billions of rows. I could explain why that is, but this video does a better job than me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=267&v=fQazhzcC-rg (the internals part is interesting). Designing app engine apps is quite different to "normal" apps. And one thing you hear again and again if you need fast responses is: use the memcache (and so should you)

Comment: konqi, I know that caching will solve my problem but this is a very simple use case. Total rows in the table is 25 and I am querying indexed fields to get only 3 records. Don't you think that if the datastore cannot handle this tiny query-load, then either Me or the DataStore are wrong somewhere. I will go through the video too and come back later if I have more questions. (Hopefully both Me and the DataStore come out to be right :)  after watching the video)

Comment: Worst case scenario: You have 25 rows distributed on 25 database nodes. If you query for them every single node has to handle your query and return the rows that match. Then all the 25 different results have to be merged into what you see as the actual result. Now it could also be the cursor query so you might want to check if your query works much faster without it. I myself try to avoid cursor queries if i can, i also feel that they are not as fast as they could be but to be honest, i don't know how cursor queries are handled in the datastore. I'll ask when i refresh my certification.

Comment: Distributing to 25 nodes should depend only on the slowest node. And since only 3 results are being returned, that means only 3 nodes would respond with some data. Rest all the other nodes would compare with just one data-point they have and return zero results. So 25 nodes distribution would actually be perfect and result should be faster than just a single node. Off course, even if you add scatter-gather time, it should still be in milliseconds. (I am just trying to think logically here, I admit I don't have any insight into GAE DS implementation).

Comment: Well, let's see if your bounty attracts one of the Google guys. You might also want to address your issue in the support group for objectify, Jeff might know more about it. I still believe that you should avoid cursor queries all together and only use those for slow running background/maintenance tasks.

Comment: @konqi I don't believe there should be any performance hit when using cursors as, to my knowledge, they just point to an offset in the relevant index/result set.  I've not had performance problems myself (albeit only paging through ~10^5 results).

Comment: @tx802 It shouldn't make a big difference in way of query speed, but you can't compare it with cursors in relational databases where the cursor is not just an offset but a reference to a position in a result set. Relational databases do not need to query data when using cursors, only initially. I'm not entirely sure whether the cursor is just an offset. If it was it could easily be a number but that's not what a datastore cursor looks like. I'll try to find out more about the cursor itself.

Comment: this is a bad idea not even considering what you might be seeing performance wise, the **$ Cost** of constantly querying the datastore is going to kill you for even a relatively small number of users. This is not they kind of activity that the datastore is designed to support *at scale*.

Comment: In case this issue is still happening for you, were you able to test it by disabling objectify’s caching as advised in this answer?