How can I diagnose slow response times from Google App Engine and Django to serve a web app?
I've deployed a Django based portfolio website - http://johnmcgurk.no - on App Engine and I am struggling to diagnose why one app has such a poor response time. When running google PageSpeed Insights the "core" app on the root url has an initial server response time of ~6s, while the secondary app (an e commerce demo) has a still bad, but much better response time of around 0.8s.
The app uses Google Cloud SQL with Postgres 14 for the database, and a Google Image bucket to serve the static and image files.
I'm completely new to hosting webapps, so an advice is much appreciated, thank you in advance!
I've searched online for tools to help me diagnose where the bottleneck is, and have run the website on my local machine using google-sql-proxy in an attempt to rule out the database as the root of the issue (also the e commerce site uses far more database queries), and haven't managed to find anything of use.

Perhaps you can start off by reviewing your Django app by trying to identify bottlenecks. django-debug-toolbar is quite useful for this.

So I've tried the django-debug-toolbar, however I was unable to run it inside GAE as the static files for the toolbar were throwing a 403 error when loaded from the google bucket the static is collected into. On my local machine both the SQL queries and the compute time are faster for the page that loads far slower on GAE. I'm unsure what to do to diagnose further.

The page also seems to randomly load in around 1.5s sometimes, so starting to strongly suspect the fault may be in the use of GAE F1 micro to run the app on, although the hope was that ideally i could diagnose this properly before spending money to upgrade the hardware.

Its a good looking page John, but you have some Javascript errors on the page. Looks like the page is just failing to download fonts, and I am not seeing anything happen on the page or web console until after those downloads fail so your code must be getting hung up here.
Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

First off, you are having trouble when you try to GET your files from Google Cloud. You have to enable CORS Cross Origin Requests to enable cross-site requests on your server. Please edit your settings.py:
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

If you decide to use an SSL certificate, you'll want to add something like this too, I also put in some of the settings to keep cross-site cookies secure because its a good practice:
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_SSL_HOST = "https://irisdocuments.com"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True

If you decide to use any HTML forms to submit data we have to consider cross-site requests too - even when we submit back to our own url - by using a csrf token:
<form action="/CreateAccount/" method="POST" id="CreateAccountForm">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label id="cemaillabel" for="cemail" class="confirmLabels">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="cemail" name="cemail">
  <br><br>
  <label id="cnamelabel" for="cname" class="confirmLabels">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname">
  <br><br>
  <label id="cpwdlabel" for="cpwd" class="confirmLabels">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="cpwd" name="cpwd">
  <br><br>
  <label id="cpwdconfirmlabel" for="cpwdconfirm" class="confirmLabels">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="cpwdconfirm" name="cpwdconfirm">
  <br><br>
  <p id="textAgreement" style="font-size: small;text-align: center;margin-top: 1%;">By clicking 'Create Account' you agree to the Iris Documents 
    <a href="https://iris1-static.s3.amazonaws.com/static/TermsAndConditions.pdf" style="display: inline;">Terms and Conditions</a> and 
    <a href="https://iris1-static.s3.amazonaws.com/static/PrivacyPolicy.pdf" style="display: inline;">Privacy Policy</a>.
  </p>
  <button type="submit" id="cConfirmButton" class="button" style="width: 180px;display: block;margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;">Create Account</button>
</form>

Just some stuff to consider with "cross-site" requests as you develop your project.
Looking around your site a bit that ecommerce site you were talking about with the auctions listings loads fine because it doesn't have any of the cross-site requests failing due to missing CORS headers. However, I did click on an auction listing and could see that you have debugging mode turned on in your settings.py. I have had some issues arise before with debugging turned on when I try to GET static files in a production level setting on a live domain. So if you are still having issues try turning debugging off.
Good luck hopefully this solves your issues and gets you solidly on your way here!

Thank you so much for your amazing and detailed advice. I have tried putting the CORS settings in the settings.py file as you suggested, as well as changing the settings on the google bucket to send the correct header, the message is now replaced with a different 403 error. Also when I remove the fonts from the css the problem persists, so not quite sure where the issue is. The ssl certificate I have set secure: always in the app.ysml file, seems to work, do I still need the SSL code in the django file? csrf token wasn't included as the page has no authentication and is not handled by my app

Oh okay yeah that works for ssl, I was seeing a red line over the ssl icon but its seems to be working now. Where are you seeing a 403 error? The page is actually loading for me fine with no web console errors. The page speed is still slow though and I am starting to think it must be the server response time as @NoCommandLine was saying. It looks like other links on the site load quickly because at the point google has "warmed up". Seems strange to me I use AWS but this other post is talking about it saying its 0.30$ a day for always on. not sure the price altogether, prob $35/mo on aws though

Similar to what @NoCommandLine was talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854821/google-app-engine-application-extremely-slow

To be honest I ran a Django site on a Ubuntu server I setup on my home network that loaded about as fast as that site does now so you could do that, I think the bottleneck was actually my server being across the house on wifi so it could be pretty good if you have fast wired connection and your isp lets you open ports 80/443 for incoming traffic on the modem. Then you just cant let your old computer turn off haha so like 15-20$ in power there a month depends on your location haha

I managed to get the fonts to load by uploading them into a common access section of the google bucket, as well as configuring the bucket to send the appropriate CORS headers. As for the response time I'm stumped. The auctions page is reliably fairly quick while the core page is almost invariably very slow. I have tried removing parts of the html, removing the javascript, removing templating elements and no matter what it seems to be slow. Thinking of giving it a rest for now and coming back to it later and run it on a server as you suggest, either at home or more likely as a cloud service.

Had one last ditch effort, removed the entirity of the HTML content, simplified the index view to remove all db calls, purged anything extra i could think of from the django files and the load time is still over 5s most of the time.

Yeah considering it takes forever to load the first page then it loads the links on the page pretty quickly, seems like it has to be the "warming up" process, @NoCommandLine was talking about. Then again, really not too big of a deal for a personal site it might be the cheapest way. Good luck with it!


Look at bullet 2 of this SO response

By default, GAE Standard is configured for 'automatic scaling' which means the instance goes down when you don't have traffic and then starts up again when it receives 'first' traffic. This startup of a new instance generally takes time.
Some ways to deal with this are
a) Tweak your code to make sure you only load libraries at the point they're needed
b) Have an instance always running and configure warmups (see docs)



Maybe so, this might be something to consider once you get your main page to load at a normal response time like your auctions page. I dont think the automatic scaling should be this exaggerated to have us waiting 6 seconds, but something to look into to keep trying to increase your page loading speeds.

Thank you so much for your response! I have looked into the logs and the trace details don't seem to be very helpful at first glance, perhaps I'm not looking in the right place, but the GET requests just seem to be listing, or example, latency: 7.911890s. I notice the responseSize is almost 4 times larger on the core page than it is on auctions, could this be to blame? And if so is it a bug in the code or an indication that I need to pay for more ram and cpu on app engine? Also I have tried running these tests with another instance open locally, should that offset the warmup effect?
